# RFECV best n_features doesn't correspond to best gridscore

Tags: machine-learning, classification, predictive-modeling, feature-selection, random-forest

I am working on a feature selection for a binary classification problem with 977 records (and class proportion of 77:23). I already referred these two related posts - [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/64770/how-to-define-the-number-of-features-to-select-in-rfecv) and [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/64856/mismatch-between-optimum-features-and-grid-scores-using-rfecv). step size = 1 and number of columns is 61

I ran the below code for `RFECV`

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
estimator = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=1,class_weight='balanced',max_depth=5,max_features='sqrt',n_estimators=500)
selector = RFECV(estimator,step=1,cv=StratifiedKFold(10),scoring='f1',verbose=2)
selector = selector.fit(X_train,y_train)
plt.figure()
plt.xlabel("Number of features selected")
plt.ylabel("Cross validation score \n of number of selected features")
plt.plot(range(1, len(selector.grid_scores_) + 1), selector.grid_scores_)
plt.show()
```

And got the below output graph

[image]

As you can see that the best score is achieved when there are 10-15 features

But RFECV returns only 4 features as optimal number of features as shown below

```
print('Optimal number of features :', selector.n_features_)
print('Best features :', X_train.columns[selector.support_])
```

> Optimal number of features : 4
> Best features : Index(['F1','F2','F3','F4'],dtype='object')

**but when I use Borutapy, Featurewiz, Sequential forward selection etc, my best feature subset is around 13-14.**

So, am wondering whether I am interpreting the RFECV output incorrectly. Why is there some inconsistency here? Am I misinterpreting the output graph? Can you guide me on this?

**update**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Some of those fold curves are a bit higher around 5 than at 15; plot the average of the fold scores instead?

Comment: I also tried `selector.cv_results_` - screenshot of which is updated. can help me interpret that please? I did see mean test score as 0.60 at 4th position. Does it mean it indicates 4 features?

Comment: I computed mean using `np.average`. Is this how it is done? - `np.average(selector.grid_scores_, axis=1)`. You can find the screenshot above

Comment: Check the average grid score from the last image you have attached here.